# Encoding issue when writing a file

Tags: node.js, character-encoding

I try to write a String in a file with Node.js but the result is not what I'm expected and I don't understand what is wrong :/

For example :

```
const fs = require('fs');

c = '€'
fs.writeFileSync("ascii.txt", c, {encoding: "ascii"});
fs.writeFileSync("utf8.txt", c, {encoding: "utf8"});
```

In this exemple I try to write the 128th char in [the extended ascii table](https://www.ascii-code.com/). In ascii Node write 0xAC(172) instead of 0x80(128)... For UTF-8 the result seem ok.
For the normal ascii table char (0 to 127) it is ok with the two encoding.

It is because ascii encoding don't support extended ascii ? In this case what should I use for simple byte to byte copy ?

Edit :

| ASCII char | Node write | remarque |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 128 | 172 |  |
| 129 | 129 |  |
| 130 | 26 |  |
| 131 | 146 |  |
| 132 | 30 |  |
| 133 | 38 |  |
| 134 | 32 |  |
| 135 | 33 |  |
| 136 | 198 |  |
| 137 | 48 |  |
| 138 | 96 |  |
| 139 | 57 |  |
| 140 | 82 |  |
| 141 | 141 | non-printable |
| 142 | 125 |  |
| 143 | 143 | non-printable |
| 144 | 144 | non-printable |
| 145 | 24 |  |

Comment: I think Node has a certain offset to the ASCII encoding, try subtracting 44 from your ASCII code and see if that works

Comment: @Mastermind I checked what you suggest and fond that it seem random... But the code is **right for the non-printable char**...